# Why base64 string has been saved as Object in mongoDB?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, http, http-headers

I want to save a product detail on the mongoDB database. And when I do this mongoBD store a property imageSrc as object. But I need to store this as string

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJaL0.png)

[my angular service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbG1.png)

[my express server request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZ9d.png)

I think it is connected with http-headers, but I cannot solve this problem

Comment: please post code as code but not as images

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that you assign the Promise to `imageSrc` and not the actual result. You should resolve the promise of `getBase64` before calling `http.post`.